# How to get an index of max value element from a list column in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a data frame:

```
pl.DataFrame({'no_of_docs':[[9,4,2],
                            [3,9,1,10],
                            [10,3,2,1],
                            [10,30],
                            [1,2,3,6,4,5]]})
```

Here the column: no_of_docs is a list[int] type one: i would like to add a new column with the max value index from each list?

Another case:

```
pl.DataFrame({'no_of_docs':[['9','4','2'],
                            ['3','9','1','10'],
                            ['10','3','2','1'],
                            ['10','30'],
                            ['1','2','3','6','4','5']]})
```

Here no_of_docs is a type of list[str] and how to convert it to int and get an index of max value.

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you answered the question mostly yourself, but in case you still need the casting to List[i64]. Here would be the solution

```
df.with_column(
    pl.col("no_of_docs").cast(pl.List(pl.Int64)).arr.arg_max().alias('idx')
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌──────────────────────┬─────┐
│ no_of_docs           ┆ idx │
│ ---                  ┆ --- │
│ list[str]            ┆ u32 │
╞══════════════════════╪═════╡
│ ["9", "4", "2"]      ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["3", "9", ... "10"] ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["10", "3", ... "1"] ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["10", "30"]         ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["1", "2", ... "5"]  ┆ 3   │
└──────────────────────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

With polars version [0.18.0](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.18.0), the list namespace accessor was renamed from `.arr` to `.list`.

You can now get the index of the maximum element using

```py
df.with_column(pl.col('no_of_docs').list.arg_max().alias('idx'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do it for list[int] type as below:

```
df.with_column(pl.col('no_of_docs').arr.arg_max().alias('idx')
```

The same thing to be done to list[str] type.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code please :

```py
df['idx']=[sub_list.index(max(sub_list)) for sub_list in df['no_of_docs']]
```

Comment: `np.argmax(sub_list)` is better than `sub_list.index(max(sub_list))`.

Comment: FYI: I'm trying to get it done in polars way not pandas.